# How to fix replytocom & comment_error_msg in my website

Tags: php, wordpress

I need your solution for my web. Sorry for my bad english.

I have a website with wordpress cms. my wp-comments-post.php is working when my web in shared hosted but after i moving my web in vps, reply & comment error not working in my web. My vps using centos 6.9 x 64, php 5.6. This is my wp-comments-post.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Handles Comment Post to WordPress and prevents duplicate comment posting.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    header('Allow: POST');
    header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    exit;
}

/** Sets up the WordPress Environment. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

nocache_headers();

$comment_post_ID = isset($_POST['comment_post_ID']) ? (int) $_POST['comment_post_ID'] : 0;

$post = get_post($comment_post_ID);

if ( empty($post->comment_status) ) {
    do_action('comment_id_not_found', $comment_post_ID);
    exit;
}

// get_post_status() will get the parent status for attachments.
$status = get_post_status($post);

$status_obj = get_post_status_object($status);

if ( !comments_open($comment_post_ID) ) {
    do_action('comment_closed', $comment_post_ID);
    wp_die( __('My error masssage.......') );
} elseif ( 'trash' == $status ) {
    do_action('comment_on_trash', $comment_post_ID);
    exit;
} elseif ( !$status_obj->public && !$status_obj->private ) {
    do_action('comment_on_draft', $comment_post_ID);
    exit;
} elseif ( post_password_required($comment_post_ID) ) {
    do_action('comment_on_password_protected', $comment_post_ID);
    exit;
} else {
    do_action('pre_comment_on_post', $comment_post_ID);
}

$comment_author       = ( isset($_POST['author']) )  ? trim(strip_tags($_POST['author'])) : null;
$comment_author_email = ( isset($_POST['email']) )   ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
$comment_author_url   = ( isset($_POST['url']) )     ? trim($_POST['url']) : null;
$comment_content      = ( isset($_POST['comment']) ) ? trim($_POST['comment']) : null;

// If the user is logged in
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( $user->ID ) {
    if ( empty( $user->display_name ) )
        $user->display_name=$user->user_login;
    $comment_author       = $wpdb->escape($user->display_name);
    $comment_author_email = $wpdb->escape($user->user_email);
    $comment_author_url   = $wpdb->escape($user->user_url);
    if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') ) {
        if ( wp_create_nonce('unfiltered-html-comment_' . $comment_post_ID) != $_POST['_wp_unfiltered_html_comment'] ) {
            kses_remove_filters(); // start with a clean slate
            kses_init_filters(); // set up the filters
        }
    }
} else {
    if ( get_option('comment_registration') || 'private' == $status )
        wp_die( __('My error masssage.......') );
}

$comment_type = '';

//MOD Customize comment error message.
//Need to add the following code to your comments.php file wherever you want error message to display:
/*
  <?php if ($_GET['comment_error_msg']) { // Display Comment Error Message ?>
    <div class="comment_error_message">Comment <?php echo $_GET['comment_error_msg']; ?><br>Note: If your comment text disappeared, try clicking your browser BACK button.</div>
  <?php } ?>
*/
$comment_error_true = false; //MOD new code
if ( '' == $comment_content ) {
    $comment_error_msg = __('&nbsp;&nbsp; My error masssage.......'); //MOD new code
    $comment_error_true = true; //MOD new code
    //wp_die( __('My error masssage.......') ); //original
}

if ( get_option('require_name_email') && !$user->ID ) {
    if ( 6 > strlen($comment_author_email) || '' == $comment_author ) {
        $comment_error_msg = __('&nbsp;&nbsp; My error masssage.......'); //MOD new code
        $comment_error_true = true; //MOD new code
        //wp_die( __('My error masssage.......') ); //original
    } elseif ( !is_email($comment_author_email)) {
        $comment_error_msg = __('&nbsp;&nbsp; My error masssage.......'); //MOD new code
        $comment_error_true = true; //MOD new code
        //wp_die( __('My error masssage.......') ); //original
    }
}

//MOD Original code is now in the ELSE statement
if (true == $comment_error_true) { //MOD new code

    //Set this to false to use default wp_die page
    $use_comment_custom_error_page = true; //MOD new code

    if ($use_comment_custom_error_page) { //MOD new code
        $location = get_permalink() . '?comment_error_msg=' . urlencode($comment_error_msg); //MOD new code
        if ( !$user->ID ) { //MOD new code
            $comment_cookie_lifetime = apply_filters('comment_cookie_lifetime', 30000000); //MOD new code
            setcookie('comment_author_' . COOKIEHASH, $comment_author, time() + $comment_cookie_lifetime, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN); //MOD new code
            setcookie('comment_author_email_' . COOKIEHASH, $comment_author_email, time() + $comment_cookie_lifetime, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN); //MOD new code
            setcookie('comment_author_url_' . COOKIEHASH, esc_url($comment_author_url), time() + $comment_cookie_lifetime, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN); //MOD new code
            //setcookie('comment_content_' . COOKIEHASH, $comment_content, time() + $comment_cookie_lifetime, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN); //MOD new code //TO DO: Figure out how to get Comment field to re-appear and not be deleted.
        } //MOD new code
    } else { //MOD new code
        wp_die($comment_error_msg); //MOD new code //This performs the default comment error page action
    } //MOD new code
} else { //MOD new code

    //Original unmodified code STARTS here
    $comment_parent = isset($_POST['comment_parent']) ? absint($_POST['comment_parent']) : 0;

    $commentdata = compact('comment_post_ID', 'comment_author', 'comment_author_email', 'comment_author_url', 'comment_content', 'comment_type', 'comment_parent', 'user_ID');

    $comment_id = wp_new_comment( $commentdata );

    $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
    if ( !$user->ID ) {
        $comment_cookie_lifetime = apply_filters('comment_cookie_lifetime', 30000000);
        setcookie('comment_author_' . COOKIEHASH, $comment->comment_author, time() + $comment_cookie_lifetime, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
        setcookie('comment_author_email_' . COOKIEHASH, $comment->comment_author_email, time() + $comment_cookie_lifetime, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
        setcookie('comment_author_url_' . COOKIEHASH, esc_url($comment->comment_author_url), time() + $comment_cookie_lifetime, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }

    $location = empty($_POST['redirect_to']) ? get_comment_link($comment_id) : $_POST['redirect_to'] . '#comment-' . $comment_id;
    $location = apply_filters('comment_post_redirect', $location, $comment);
    //Original unmodified code ENDS here

} //MOD new code

wp_redirect($location);
exit;
?>
```

Please help me.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue on my own WordPress site. You can solve this issue simply by delete the following code from your wp-comments-post.php page.

```
if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    header('Allow: POST');
    header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    exit;
}
```

I hope it works...